# simultaneous independent time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a number of independent time series. With the term independent I mean that they are not multivariate time series. There is not direct relationship between them (there is not any variable or lag from one time series that participates to another time series) that would make it a VAR problem.

So we can imagine a matrix whose rows are different time series and columns are their values over time.
To make forecasting with this matrix the obvious solution would be to create a forecasting model for each one of them.
I want to ask if someone can suggest some other method that might transform the problem to something simpler. It is an open question and I would like suggestions, opinion, etc. A solution is not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler"?

Comment: This is the most common format of representing multiple time series... what do you have in mind as "simpler problem"? You usually don't get to define the problem, it usually is "predict the next x values of these N series".

Comment: if they are truly independent you will just want to fit univariate time series models to each series

Comment: You can trivially parallelize your calculations. It doesn't get any simpler than that. I don't quite see what you have in mind.

Comment: As others have stated you are probably better off fitting each one to a standard time series model.  With that said you may have a ton of series so it may be computationally efficient to not train each one individually.  In that case you could try flattening your data set and creating an id column and an id for each of your previous columns(or rows), then you have to create id specific time series features which could be harmonic series and piecewise linear basis functions or lagged values and rolling values.  Then you can encode your id column and pass everything to a RF or something.

Comment: All answers are logical and acceptable. Even Chris Haug, who just asked "What I mean by simpler". 
Tylerr, by saying "it is not efficient to train each one of the set of the time series", just got my spirit. He also suggested something.
Another answer could be to try to convert the full dataset to one time series somehow. Do something with this. But you must be able to populate the results to the original time series.